# Error during SonarQube Scanner execution java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarscanner

I'm using sonar 7.7 and at the time of scanning to a php project I get the error below.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.sonar.php.checks.IdenticalOperandsInBinaryExpressionCheck.visitBinaryExpression(IdenticalOperandsInBinaryExpressionCheck.java:43)
        at org.sonar.php.tree.impl.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:75)
        at org.sonar.plugins.php.api.visitors.PHPVisitorCheck.scan(PHPVisitorCheck.java:549)
```

Comment: Can you provide a few more lines of the stacktrace? It would be useful to see where the recursion is. Also, is your PHP project accessible at all?

Comment: only these three lines appear countless times in the error